# A good & simple way to automate populating a script template with variables?

Tags: scripting

I have a bit of a conundrum. I have a very basic script template, which you can see here as an example:

```
track DarkIsRising {
    sound = CassettePortSulphurBandDarkIsRising(1895),
    duration = 10,
}

track DeathIsABirdFlying {
    sound = CassettePortSulphurBandDeathIsaBirdFlying(1895),
    duration = 25,
}
```

For the purposes here, I have 1,225 tracks that need to have these variables filled. I have all of these names and durations already set aside and ready to be plugged in, but the idea of doing this by hand is daunting and I'm not really a coder, I'm just trying to kludge something together--so this is all kind of new to me.

If there is a way to essentially take an organized list of this data and turn it into a list of entries like these, that would save me hours of very boring work. Googling hasn't turned up any solutions that I could even start to implement with my level of expertise, so I apologize if this seems like an incredibly basic question.

Comment: It might help to at least explain what language you are using. The code you posted looks like a lot of different languages.

Comment: @braX To be honest, I figured the language wouldn't be much help as this is mostly a question of 'what would be the most effective way to do this text operation', but I'm writing in Lua (at least I think? Whatever language Project Zomboid uses for its scripts.) Must emphasize that I can in no way be considered a 'coder' and I'm just bashing things together until they work.